# ngsw-worker.js is not added with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-universal

We have implemented PWA (@angular/service-worker) and in prod mode everything works as expected. We are using angular universal.
But in dev mode, the file "ngsw-worker.js" is not generated.

I already changed the registration to enabled on all environments:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: true,
})
```

And of course it's added in angular.json:

```
  "projects": {
    "client-app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          }
```

But the file is still not generated, I cannot find any reference to this file in the code. We use "npm run dev:ssr" which is part of the angular universal template to run the app in development environment. My guess is that the serviceworker is not built with this command.

The browser shows this message since it cannot find this file and is trying to read the index file which it's redirected to:

> home-routing.module.ts:19 Service worker registration failed with:
> DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('http://localhost:4200/') with script
> ('http://localhost:4200/ngsw-worker.js'): The script has an
> unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

We need to be able to test PWA features during development as well.

How can we add this file in dev build?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to test service-worker locally with Angular universal:

- Run "npm run build" which compiles the browser script files.
- Copy the files "ngsw.json, ngsw-worker.js, safety-worker.js, worker-basic.min.js" from "dist\<app>\browser"
- Run "npm run dev:ssr" which will compile the browser and the server script files
- Copy the files back to "dist\<app>\browser"

Now you have the scripts also when using the angular universal dev server.

Comment: Does the browser register the service worker? As far as I'm aware, most browsers won't register one if you're not on HTTPS

Comment: They may certainly do it on localhost, which is treated as HTTPS by browsers

Comment: It does at least with chrome. Also you can also run Angular locally with ssl. Although I didn't manage to do it with angular universal (Seems to have a bug).